# Балансировщик сети, реализация идентификации запросов

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, клиент-сервер

Есть задача реализовать мониторинг+разгрузку на серваках в сети: допустим у нас имеется облачное хранилище с кучей серверов и это всё должно нагружаться равномерно. Мониторинг делается на основе Nagios.

Проблема возникла с реализацией аутентификации запросов.

Под аутентификацией здесь понимается идентификация запросов клиентских машин к нашим серверам с целью проверки обоснованности этих запросов.

Представьте, клиент подключается сначала к балансировщику, балансировщик анализирует текущую загруженность серверов и перенаправляет запрос на один из них. При этом сервер уведомляется о том, что у него появился новый абонент. Однако, если сервера имеют "белые" IP, ничто не мешает клиенту в обход балансировщика подключиться к одному из них. Чтобы этого не происходило нужно проверять некий id клиента на сервере, устанавливая подключился ли клиент сам (тогда его нужно блокировать), либо его перенаправил балансировщик (тогда можно предоставить доступ).

Собственно вопрос в следующем, как реализовать идентификацию запросов пользователя и можно ли это сделать средствами плагинов или следует делать как-то еще?

Comment: Nagios тут какбы не при делах, балансировкой загрузки pacemaker обычно занимается. А у него внутри ssl.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, данная задача отпала.